# How do I send slack notification using lambda (python) of sns alert

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I get sns event in json object to my emails but I want specific part to be sent to slack notification using lambda. I want time, event name, group id, event id etc to be parsed and send to slack. I tried various example online but keep getting error. I have a cloudwatch event which monitor if someone used 0.0.0.0/0 on a given security group. If this happen this will trigger cloud watch event associated to sns alert. I have integrated email alert but i want this done on slack. I Need guidance on this, i tried other example online  ?

```
*{
  "version": "0",
  "id": "5391448e-1276-49f1-d5a2-5b4898b1f863",
  "detail-type": "AWS API Call via CloudTrail",
  "source": "aws.ec2",
  "account": "982239453305",
  "time": "2019-10-02T10:07:07Z",
  "region": "eu-west-1",
  "resources": [],
  "detail": {
    "eventVersion": "1.05",
    "userIdentity": {
      "type": "AssumedRole",
      "principalId": "AROAIZE22Q5MDGTLWB2FW:jahmed",
      "arn": "arn:aws:sts::988339453305:assumed-role/dp-admins/arahman",
      "accountId": "988339453305",
      "accessKeyId": "*******",
      "sessionContext": {
        "sessionIssuer": {
          "type": "Role",
          "principalId": "********",
          "arn": "arn:aws:iam::988569453305:role/dp-admins",
          "accountId": "988569453305",
          "userName": "dp-admins"
        },
        "webIdFederationData": {},
        "attributes": {
          "mfaAuthenticated": "true",
          "creationDate": "2019-10-02T10:05:55Z"
        }
      }
    },
    "eventTime": "2019-10-02T10:07:07Z",
    "eventSource": "ec2.amazonaws.com",
    "eventName": "RevokeSecurityGroupIngress",
    "awsRegion": "eu-west-1",
    "sourceIPAddress": "195.89.75.182",
    "userAgent": "console.ec2.amazonaws.com",
    "requestParameters": {
      "groupId": "sg-00d088d28c60e6bd0",
      "ipPermissions": {
        "items": [
          {
            "ipProtocol": "tcp",
            "fromPort": 0,
            "toPort": 0,
            "groups": {},
            "ipRanges": {
              "items": [
                {
                  "cidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0",
                  "description": "test-MUST-REMOVE!"
                }
              ]
            },
            "ipv6Ranges": {},
            "prefixListIds": {}
          },
          {
            "ipProtocol": "tcp",
            "fromPort": 0,
            "toPort": 0,
            "groups": {},
            "ipRanges": {},
            "ipv6Ranges": {
              "items": [
                {
                  "cidrIpv6": "::/0",
                  "description": "test-MUST-REMOVE!"
                }
              ]
            },
            "prefixListIds": {}
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "responseElements": {
      "requestId": "93fc850f-65e7-464f-b2e0-3db1753a0c94",
      "_return": true
    },
    "requestID": "93fc850f-65e7-464f-b2e0-3db1753a0c94",
    "eventID": "2aa40c8d-cc28-45af-89c8-e8885d98dc00",
    "eventType": "AwsApiCall"
  }
}*
```

Comment: Please provide detailed information (code sample preferable) on what you have tried and what error you are getting so that we can help.

Answer (score 4):

- This is the code i have used to integrate with slack
- Read the SNS message then post the message on slack webhook url.

```
import json
import logging
import os
from urllib2 import Request, urlopen, URLError, HTTPError
# Read all the environment variables
SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL = os.environ['SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL']
SLACK_USER = os.environ['SLACK_USER']
SLACK_CHANNEL = os.environ['SLACK_CHANNEL']

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    logger.info("Event: " + str(event))
    # Read message posted on SNS Topic
    message = json.loads(event['Records'][0]['Sns']['Message'])
    logger.info("Message: " + str(message))
# Construct a new slack message
    slack_message = {
        'channel': SLACK_CHANNEL,
        'username': SLACK_USER,
        'text': "%s" % (message)
    }
# Post message on SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL
    req = Request(SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL, json.dumps(slack_message))
    try:
        response = urlopen(req)
        response.read()
        logger.info("Message posted to %s", slack_message['channel'])
    except HTTPError as e:
        logger.error("Request failed: %d %s", e.code, e.reason)
    except URLError as e:
        logger.error("Server connection failed: %s", e.reason)
```